TypeError: Argument 2 passed to VideoPermissionsHooks::onUploadVerifyFile() must be an instance of User, string given
I am working on an extension for Mediawiki. The extension is to give permissions to user the ability to upload video files. Not sure why I keep getting this error but all docs I am reading says I needed not to use global wgUser and specify it as parameter in the function.
Error Message:
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to VideoPermissionsHooks::onUploadVerifyFile() must be an instance of User, string given


VideoPermissionsHooks.php
<?php

class VideoPermissionsHooks {
    /**
     * Hook: BeforePageDisplay
     * @param OutputPage $out
     * @param Skin $skin
     */
    public static function onBeforePageDisplay( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin ) {
        // Check if the user has permission to view videos
        if ( !$out->getUser()->isAllowed( 'view_video' ) ) {
            $out->addModules( 'ext.VideoPermissions.noVideo' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hook: UploadVerifyFile
     * @param UploadBase $upload
     * @param User $user
     * @param string $mime
     * @param bool $error
     * @param string[] &$warnings
     * @return bool
     */

    public static function onUploadVerifyFile( $upload, User $user, $mime, &$error, array &$warnings ) {
        global $wgVideoPermissionEnable;

        // Check if video permissions feature is enabled
        if ( !$wgVideoPermissionEnable ) {
            return true; // Bypass checks if the feature is disabled
        }

        $fileName = $upload->getLocalFile()->getName();
        $fileExtension = strtolower( pathinfo( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

        // Verify if the user has permission to upload video files
        if ( $fileExtension === 'mp4' ) {
            if ( !$user->isAllowed( 'upload_video' ) ) {
                $error = 'You do not have permission to upload video files.';
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

Updated function:
 public static function onUploadVerifyUpload( UploadBase $upload, User $user, $mime, &$error, array &$warnings ) {
        MWDebug::log( __METHOD__ . ": onUploadVerifyFile function called" );
        MWDebug::log( __METHOD__ . ": Type of \$user: " . (is_object($user) ? get_class($user) : gettype($user)) );
        MWDebug::log( __METHOD__ . ": Value of \$user: " . print_r($user, true) );
    
        if (is_string($user)) {
            MWDebug::log( __METHOD__ . ": Error: \$user is a string" );
        }
    
        global $wgVideoPermissionEnable;
    
        // Check if video permissions feature is enabled
        if (!$wgVideoPermissionEnable) {
            return true; // Bypass checks if the feature is disabled
        }
    
        // Get the file name
        $fileName = $upload->getLocalFile()->getName();
        MWDebug::log( __METHOD__ . ": File name: " . $fileName );

        // Extract the file extension
        $fileExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        MWDebug::log( __METHOD__ . ": File extension: " . $fileExtension );
    
        // Verify if the user has permission to upload video files
        if ($fileExtension === 'mp4') {
            if (!$user->isAllowed('upload_video')) {
                $warnings[] = ['upload-video-permission-warning', $user->getName(), $fileName];
                MWDebug::log( __METHOD__ . ": User does not have permission to upload video files" );
                return false; // Prevent the upload
            }
        }
    
        return true; // Allow the upload
    }

UPDATE #2
Localsettings.php- These settings should block the all users from being to upload.
$wgEnableUploads = true;
# Specify permitted file types
$wgFileExtensions = array('png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf', 'doc','mp4');

$wgGroupPermissions['*']['upload_video'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['view_video'] = false;



VideoPermissionHooks.php
<?php


class VideoPermissionsHooks {
    /**
     * Hook: BeforePageDisplay
     * @param OutputPage $out
     * @param Skin $skin
     */
    public static function onBeforePageDisplay( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin ) {
        // Check if the user has permission to view videos
        if ( !$out->getUser()->isAllowed( 'view_video' ) ) {
            $out->addModules( 'ext.VideoPermissions.noVideo' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hook: UploadVerifyUpload
     * @param UploadBase $upload
     * @param User $user
     * @param string $pageText
     * @param string &$error
     */

    public static function onUploadVerifyUpload( UploadBase $upload, User $user, $pageText, &$error ) {
        $fileName = strtolower( pathinfo(  $upload->getLocalFile()->getName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION
        ) );
        global $wgVideoPermissionEnable;
        if ( $wgVideoPermissionEnable && $fileName === 'mp4' && !$user->isAllowed( 'upload_video' ) ) {
            $error = [ 'upload-video-permission-warning', $user->getName(), $fileName ];
        }
    }
}


You have defined your hooked function VideoPermissionsHooks::onUploadVerifyFile() as specified in the example on MediaWiki help page.
The example is irrelevant and misleading. The real signature of UploadVerifyHook::onUploadVerifyFile() is $upload, $mime, &$error as quoted at the top of that page. You can see it in the source code. This is how it is called by MediaWiki code.
The signature starting with $upload, User $user, … belongs to another hook UploadVerifyUpload, which you should use instead of UploadVerifyFile, Actually, it is UploadBase $upload, User $user, array|null $props, string $comment, string|false $pageText, array|essageSpecifier|null &$error) (documentation, whence this hook is called).
So, this hook could be made simpler:
public static function onUploadVerifyUpload( UploadBase $upload, User $user, $pageText, &$error ) {
    $fileName = strtolower( pathinfo(
        && $upload->getLocalFile()->getName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION
    ) );
    global $wgVideoPermissionEnable;
    if ( $wgVideoPermissionEnable && $fileName === 'mp4' && !$user->isAllowed( 'upload_video' ) ) {
        $error = [ 'upload-video-permission-warning', $user->getName(), $fileName ];
    }
}


Im following what youre saying but now i am getting this error [67bf20504d26ef74a4d01799] /wiki/Special:Upload TypeError: Argument 5 passed to VideoPermissionsHooks::onUploadVerifyUpload() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/w/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php on line 338

Just remove array from onUploadVerifyUpload() signature: MediaWiki can pass other types to that hook.

Ok I have a question, first the function works so thank you for the explanation. But Is there anything that mediawiki has that will allow a user to upload regardless if they have the permission to upload Mp4 or not. Because my user although doesnt have videopermissions i was able to upload a video still.

Tbh its not working as expecting. I am suspecting that the function is not even being called once i removed the array from the warning because I disable the check to see if the etension was enable. Both users still was able to upload a video without having the permissions.

My advice was to declare your hook as follows: public static function onUploadVerifyUpload( UploadBase $upload, User $user, $mime, &$error, &$warnings ).

Yes I do have it like that.   public static function onUploadVerifyUpload( UploadBase $upload, User $user, $mime, &$error,&$warnings ).  The issue is that the user can still upload a video file, while not being apart of the group.

I should have checked onUploadVerifyUpload's signature better. See the updated answer.

So i updated with what you suggested and still user is able to upload a video file. which doesnt makes sense as to why. check update question to see all what i have including localsettings.php
